# Unable to recognize the global variables set in Ubuntu

Tags: makefile, ubuntu-14.04, iot

I have been following the steps mentioned here [Google Weave-Libiota](http://weave.googlesource.com/weave/libiota/+/HEAD/docs/GETTING_STARTED.md) on Ubuntu. It's been successful until running test step. Later on, we need to write a header file defining the api_keys, Client_secret key and client_id and set its path to a Global Environment variable so that the program main.c uses API KEY file through header files and Global variable. But it's not recognizing.

Errors to the command `make -C /host/examples/light` image:

```
wozartubuntu@wozartubuntu-iMac:~$ cd libiota/

wozartubuntu@wozartubuntu-iMac:~/libiota$ sudo make -C examples/host/light/

[sudo] password for wozartubuntu: 

make: Entering directory '/home/wozartubuntu/libiota/examples/host/light'
gcc  -Wall -Werror -Os -fno-builtin -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fstack-usage  -DIOTA_BUILD_TIME=1485236028 -DSUPPORTS_FLOATING_POINT_FORMAT -I/usr/local/include -std=gnu99  -MMD -I$IOTA_ROOT -I$IOTA_ROOT/include -DJSMN_PARENT_LINKS -DJSMN_SHORT_TOKENS -I$IOTA_ROOT/third_party/jsmn -c -o /home/wozartubuntu/libiota/out/host/examples/light/main.o /home/wozartubuntu/libiota/examples/host/light/main.c
In file included from /home/wozartubuntu/libiota/examples/host/light/main.c:22:0:
/home/wozartubuntu/libiota/include/iota/oauth_keys.h:23:38: fatal error: IOTA_OAUTH2_KEYS_HEADER.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
../../../examples/host/common.mk:33: recipe for target '/home/wozartubuntu/libiota/out/host/examples/light/main.o' failed
make: *** [/home/wozartubuntu/libiota/out/host/examples/light/main.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/wozartubuntu/libiota/examples/host/light'
wozartubuntu@wozartubuntu-iMac:~/libiota$
```

Program causing the error:

```
/* 
* Copyright 2016 Google Inc.

 *

 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");

 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.

 * You may obtain a copy of the License at

 *

 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 *

 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software

 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,

 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.

 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and

 * limitations under the License.

 */


#ifndef LIBIOTA_INCLUDE_IOTA_OAUTH_KEYS_H_
#define LIBIOTA_INCLUDE_IOTA_OAUTH_KEYS_H_




#include "IOTA_OAUTH2_KEYS_HEADER" 




#endif  // LIBIOTA_INCLUDE_IOTA_OAUTH_KEYS_H_
```

How to resolve these errors?

Comment: Please post the console output as formatted text, not an image. Images are not compatible with clipboards, search engines and screen-readers, and are thus not so easy to work with. Thanks.

Comment: Please refer the question now, Thanks :)

Comment: OK, better, thanks. I've removed the screenshot. If there was any info in the screenshot that is not in your code please edit again, this time using the code formatting tools, as per my edit.

Comment: no, thank you so much. that is it. everything has been included. no more editing

Comment: as far as I know, the compiler is not able to get the info which is inside the global variable "IOTA_OAUTH2_KEYS_HEADER". and the path set to "IOTA_OAUTH2_KEYS_HEADER" contains a header file which has API key, client key and client secret key. but I am unable to understand why is the error No such file or directory.

Comment: just now, I made changes to main.c program by adding API key, client ID and client secret key in the main.c itself without using "IOTA_OAUTH2_KEYS_HEADER" as header and linking process etc, so the above fatal error is solved. but now curl_httpc.c:(.text.ssl_ctx_addcert_+0x2b): undefined reference to 'x509_store_new'..and so on